# Crear un procedimiento almacenado sin parametros en ORACLE

Tags: oracle-11g

Soy nuevo en este motor de base de datos, estoy que creo un store procedure y cuando lo creo no hay ningún problema, pero al ejecutarlo me sale esto:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00905: object WEB_SEGURIDAD.SIMEXA_SP_DEPARTAMENTOS_UBIGEO is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**Mi código es este:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SIMEXA_SP_DEPARTAMENTOS_UBIGEO"
AS
       BEGIN
         SELECT DISTINCT dpto FROM up100.UBIGEO;
       END;
```

**Llamando al stored procedure:**

```
BEGIN
  SIMEXA_SP_DEPARTAMENTOS_UBIGEO;
END;
```

Comment: El problema no es la falta de parámetros. Lo que es inválido dentro del SP es hacer un `select` sin recoger el resultado, eso no tiene sentido en _oracle_. Sospecho que aprendiste esto en _SQL Server_, que es dónde he visto la práctica. ¿Qué es lo que pretendes lograr?

Comment: Efectivamente amigo jachguate jejeje, si vengo de ese mundo del sqlserver, pero no me quiero quedar ahí, por eso estoy que aprendo distintos motores de base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iniciaré mi respuesta diciendo que *Oracle* no es *SQL Server*, dónde he visto esta práctica.

Lo más cercano que, en mi opinión, puedes hacer en *Oracle*, es retornar un [`RefCursor`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_plsql.htm#TDPNG60000), que es básicamente un conjunto de datos, pero no puedes simplemente ejecutar una o varias sentencias `select` y esperar que el motor recoja el resultado  y de alguna manera *lo devuelva*, como si ocurre en *SQL Server*.

La sintaxis, sería algo como esta:

En SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create procedure miProc (prc out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4     open prc for select * from emp;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> execute miProc(:rc)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE           SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-1981       4999                    10
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-1981       2849                    30
      7782 CLARKE     MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-1981       2449                    10
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-1981       2974                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09-DEC-1982       2999                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-1981       2999                    20
      7369 SMITHY     CLERK           7902 17-DEC-1980       9988         11         20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-1981       1599       3009         30
      7521 WARDS      SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-1981       1249        551         30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-1981       1249       1400         30
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-1981       1499          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12-JAN-1983       1099                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-1981        949                    30
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-1982       1299                    10
      6668 Umberto    CLERK           7566 11-JUN-2009      19999          0         10
      9567 ALLBRIGHT  ANALYST         7788 02-JUN-2009      76999         24         10
```

Con información de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170548/get-resultset-from-oracle-stored-procedure) de StackOverflow en inglés.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación "jachguate", ahora si me pondré manos a la obra :D.